# leaving a spoon in a cup of tap water for about 12 hours makes a pattern of bubbles, why?

Tags: aqueous-solution, water

I left the spoon in the water after showing the cup from the tea that I was drinking last night makes a spoon like the pattern of bubbles

[image: this is what it look like]

[image: see]

Comment: Maybe it is just the gases naturally contained in the tap water, or maybe the spoon reacts with water. The former option seems more likely, but we need more experiments.

Comment: If the tap water is relatively rich in gaseous $\ce{CO2}$ at the source, which is easier at low temperature, this gas will slowly get out of the water when stored in a warmer place where the air contains few $\ce{CO2}$. The spoon may here serve as catalyzer of this reaction.

Comment: I agree with @Ivanneretin it looks like escaping of dissolved gases, as they have lower solubility in warmed up water. The spoon acts as a condensation center for gas bubbles  and temporal heat conductor during water warming up. The spoon edges are the most exposed to the water, so the most effective in both ways.

Comment: What you're asking isn't just why do you get bubbles, but why do the bubbles form a pattern at the surface that corresponds to the outline of a spoon.  I'm guessing what's happening is the spoon-like pattern on the surface is caused because bubbles selectively form at the edges of the spoon.  Then, when they rise straight up to the surface, you get a pattern that replicates the edge of the spoon. This naturally leads to the question:  Why do the bubbles selectively form at the edges or, to put it another way, why do they selectively form on extremely high-curvature surfaces?